# Sidebar automatically adjust to icon size change in system preferences

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

[Adopt the new look of macOS - WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020-10104/?time=1460):

> here we can see that NSOutlineView automatically scales both the text labels and the symbol images to match the preferred sidebar size in system preferences. This makes it really easy to support all three sizes in your sidebar.

How does the *NSOutlineView* or *NSTableView* need to be setup for this to work? If you add *Outline View* or *Source List* in Interface Builder this doesn't work out of the box.

[image: System Preferences > General > Sidebar icon size]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you added *Outline View* or *Source List* in Interface Builder, select the Outline View object and go to the Size Inspector.

Change *Row Size Style* from ***Match Canvas*** to ***Default***.

[image: Size Inspector - Row Size Style - Default]

**Tech note:** Under the hood this is done with the *NSTableViewDefaultSizeMode* global user defaults key.